# How to set ssm param locally for serverless offline

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I recently starting working on serverless architecture. Here is example of serverless.xml for the same.

```
test:
    name: test
    handler: handler.lambda_handler
    timeout: 6
    environment:
      APP_ID: ${ssm:/path/to/ssm/test~true}
```

Now when I am trying to run serverless offline command then it complains about ssm variable. 
Following is the error that coming on console.

I want to run everything on my locally machine for development. Can someone help on this how I can solve this problem.

```
ServerlessError: Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable ${ssm:/path/to/ssm/test~true}. Please make sure the value of the property is a string.
      at Variables.populateVariable (C:\Users\kumarn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\Variables.js:464:13)
      at Variables.renderMatches (C:\Users\kumarn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\Variables.js:386:21)
      at C:\Users\kumarn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\Variables.js:406:29
  From previous event:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this by adding the plugin:

https://github.com/janders223/serverless-offline-ssm

if you're feeling more adventurous you can also use localstack https://github.com/localstack/localstack

note that free version does not support everything

Comment: Its working and I am able to see all my endpoint, can you please help me to see how can run swagger for doc locally, already installed serverless-swagger plugin.
I config the port for API and its working do we have some config to run swagger as well for doc purpose.

Comment: as far as i know there's no plugin for swagger, but assuming you want to have the validation part you can consider using in the past i used swagger tools as middleware for express js https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools. Right now i think this one is deprecated but i'm sure there should exist something similar